# Is there any difference between including JavaScript right before the </body> tag and right before the </html> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it wrong to place the <script> tag after the </body> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037725/is-it-wrong-to-place-the-script-tag-after-the-body-tag)

```
//scripts
</body>
</html>
```

or

```
</body>
//scripts
</html>
```

I know it's kind of a silly question but is there any difference between these two methods. I've read in books to do just before the `</body>` tag but in practice I've seen people do it just before the `</html>` tag. My instincts and current findings say that it shouldn't matter I don't think it would but being as I'm newer to web development I always second guess my work cause there could be something I don't know about.

Comment: I don't believe the `<script>` tag is a valid child of `<html>`.

Comment: I don't think tags are allowed outside the head or body tag.

Comment: It's not valid HTML, <script> is valid in the <head> or within <body> & nowhere else

Comment: This seems like the type of question that could be answered just by looking at the [W3C HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/scripting-1.html#the-script-element). Just sayin'...

Comment: @BrianDriscoll Wait? This stuff is standardized? `:P`

Comment: If you are reffering to why some scripts are loaded **before the closing `</body>`** instead of **inside the `<head>`** then these might help: - [Putting jQuery/javascript source pages before end of body tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343392/putting-jquery-javascript-source-pages-before-end-of-body-tag) and [Move jQuery to the end of body tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220956/move-jquery-to-the-end-of-body-tag)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comments are correct: `<script>` outside the `head` or `body` are not valid HTML.

[Here is the relevant spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/the-root-element.html#the-html-element)

> Content Model
>
> ```
> A head element followed by a body element.
> ```

Comment: "*If I just repeat what was said in the comments, and post it as an answer, I'll get lots of rep. I'm a genius!*" `:P`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas hey, if the commenters don't want the rep, I'll take it. ;-) That said, I've added the relevant info.

Comment: @Mathletics The question should actually be closed, which is why the commenters haven't bothered posting answers.

Comment: @Mathletics You referenced the HTML 5.1 nightly spec? OMG, I love you. `:)`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas now that the exact dupe has been found, it shall be closed.

Comment: @jfrej I blame the hats.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but in my experience, as long as your JS is in the header or body tag, it doesn't make a large difference where you place your JS.

I and my coworkers always place our JS in the header tag (for readability and consistency). But I've read ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196702/where-to-place-javascript-in-a-html-file) and [here](http://robertnyman.com/2008/04/23/where-to-include-javascript-files-in-a-document/)) that to get the best performance you should place you JS just before your closing BODY tag. Again, in my experience I haven't noticed a major performance difference.